# Why does test say unexpected parenthesis?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an `if` line in my shell script that looks like this:

```
if [ 0 -lt 2 -o (0 -gt 3 ) ]
```

and this gives the error:

```
line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So I looked at `man test` to be sure that parens were supported, and sure enough, very near the top of the man page, they are! What gives!?

The example above doesn't exactly match the code because I was trying to clean it to prove a point, but this is [my repo](https://github.com/Narvey/linuxTrello) if you needed context.

EDIT: changed the if line to match the error.

Comment: FYI, this is a bug that http://www.shellcheck.net/ can detect automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parenthesis are passed to the `test` command *as arguments*. The `[ ... ]` expression is just another way to type the `test` command. The only difference is that the last argument for the `[` command must be `]`.

So you should escape the parenthesis just as any other arguments you pass to a command to avoid the shell interpretation:

```
if [ \( $# -lt 2 \) -o \( $# -gt 3 \) ]
```

Alternatively, use single quotes:

```
if [ '(' $# -lt 2 ')' -o '(' $# -gt 3 ')' ]
```

From the info page:

```
`test'
`['
          test EXPR

     Evaluate a conditional express ion EXPR and return a status of 0
     (true) or 1 (false).  Each operator and operand must be a separate
     argument.
```

By the way, the expression could be rewritten as follows:

```
if builtin test \( $# -lt 2 \) -o \( $# -gt 3 \)
```

Comment: +1 May be useful to indicate that the POSIX (~UNIX) spec limits the number of arguments to 4 (search for >4) in:  [A little above this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_06)

Comment: Also worth noting (from the same linked page): "The XSI extensions specifying the `-a` and `-o` binary primaries and the `(` and `)` operators _have been marked obsolescent_. (Many expressions using them are ambiguously defined by the grammar depending on the specific expressions being evaluated.)". The recommendation is to use separate `test` / `[` statements instead, and combine them with `&&` / `||`.

Answer (score 3):

You have unnecessary `(...)` inside `[ ... ]` that are unescaped and unquoted causing syntax error.

You can use this instead:

```
[[ $# -lt 2 || $# -gt 3 ]]
```

Or else use:

```
[[ $# -lt 2 ]] || [[ $# -gt 3 ]]
```

Comment: interesting, I thought it was because of quoting, but I'm guessing this expression `$# -lt 2` would always return something - either `0` or `1` so its not a quoting issue. So I think you are right.

Comment: But note also that the shell treats `[[` differently than `[`. Among other differences, it allows the use of unescaped parentheses. So the asker could in fact just change his `[ ... ]` to `[[ ... ]]` and keep his parentheses.

Comment: yes, even though they are not necessary here, parens `(...)` are the way you increase the precedence for a conditional expression in  a shell - so, per rob mayoff comments, the `[[ ... ]]` syntax would allow a more readable use of parens in conditionals.

Comment: @anubhava: I wouldn't say the parentheses are *unnecessary*, but plain wrong. But one point strikes me: If I use parens in an odd way, for example `[ ( ls ) ]`, bash complains that the unepected token would be *ls*, **not the parenthese**. Indeed,  if I reproduce the example, I get the message *bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$#'*. This makes me wonder, whether the OP **really** uses bash.

Comment: Yes, I use bash, but it looks like I was testing a bunch of versions of the if statement and mismatched the error and statement that I posted.  This is fixed as of the most recent edit.

Comment: Good alternative solutions, but note that subshells do not come into play here: if `(` and `)` are interpreted by the _shell_ they break the command (and no subshell is ever created). If `(` and `)` are properly quoted, they are interpreted by `[` / `test`, where they are _operators_ that define precedence (the concept of a subshell doesn't come into play at all).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, indeed `( ... )` won't create any subshell inside `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 3):

Though this solution doesn't directly answer the question, but here's an alternate way that uses C style [arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), which is effective if you're dealing with numbers in `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( "$#" < 2 || "$#" > 3 )); then
```

Comment: This does not answer `Why does test say unexpected parenthesis?` question at all. If you want to suplement existing answer, post a comment to it.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: totally agree with you, wanted to stress the point, if the author could have used this way of comparison, he wouldn't have ended up with that error in the first place. Thought that deserved a proper answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14366915)

Comment: @TobySpeight: Am not sure I agree on that, read my above comment MarcinOrlowski. This is just an alternative syntax for the author to use to avoid such errors.

Comment: well, as the OP, I appreciate this information, but I suppose I would appreciate it just as much as a comment as an answer, so that suggestion has merit as well.

Comment: I agree that this is worth having as an answer, though a preface along the lines of "this doesn't directly answer the question, but here's a superior alternative solution" might help. As an aside: the double quotes around `"$#"` can be omitted (I don't think there's ever a good reason to double-quote a variable reference inside `(( ... ))` / `$(( ... ))`, and variables can be referenced without the `$` sigil.)

Comment: all: added a clause as @mklement0 suggested!